# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when I use Series.str.len() in pandas query?

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered an issue that when I use Series.str.len() in pandas query method, and actually all the functions for Series.str is not supported in some of my envs, but work in other envs, and all these envs have almost same version of pandas and numpy. (I'm sure Series.str.xxxxx could work in all my envs before)

**Env1**

Python 3.9.7

numpy==1.21.4

pandas==1.3.4

When I ran `pd.DataFrame(columns=['core_text']).query("core_text.str.len()>1")`, it raised

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4060, in query
> res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4191, in eval
> return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py", line 353, in eval
> ret = eng_inst.evaluate()
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/engines.py", line 80, in evaluate
> res = self._evaluate()
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/engines.py", line 120, in _evaluate
> _check_ne_builtin_clash(self.expr)
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/engines.py", line 36, in _check_ne_builtin_clash
> names = expr.names
> File "/Users/huhon/miniconda3/envs/venv_dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 834, in names
> return frozenset(term.name for term in com.flatten(self.terms))
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

**Env2**

Python 3.9.9

numpy==1.21.4

pandas==1.3.4

It works perfected.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Hong

Comment: Can you check if 1) `numexpr` is installed 2) the version in each env, please?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @Corralien Yes, it was numexpr! It works now after I uninstalled numexpr, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the versions of `numexpr`. This module evaluates all string expressions for `Pandas` like `query` or `pd.eval`.

The solution is to upgrade your version of `numexpr` (or remove and reinstall it).